# Как отследить потерю фокуса динамически добавленного input?

Tags: jquery

На страницу динамически добавляются такие input:

```
<input type="text" name="first_name[]" class="form-control fname" required>
```

Я отслеживаю потерю фокуса каждого из них.

Но не совсем понял, как обратиться к динамически созданному input.

Например, вот такой код не срабатывает:

```
$('input[class="form-control fname"]').focusout(function() {
  alert('f. out');
});
```

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: [так же как с обработкой любого другого события для динамически добавленных элементов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery%5D+%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F+%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85+%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решениие:

```
$(document).on("focusout", "input[class='form-control fname']", function () {
    alert('f. out');
});
```

Comment: `document` замените на ближайшего общего предка всех ваших инпутов этих, а это безобразие с `input[class=...]` замените на `.fname`, или `input.fname`